# Can the spread operator be used to supply function arguments?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm writing class that extends statelessWidget, its build method returns `Text()` widget. and I need to pass to it text options (alignment, stile etc.) that came from constructor in `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. Why I can't use `spread` operator like this

```
final Map textOptions;
final String text;

build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text, ...textOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You currently can use the spread operator only for collection literals (`[]` for `List`, `{}` for `Map` or `Set`).

From [Bob Nystrom's article](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c) introducing Dart 2.3's new features:

> A spread can only appear in a place that can gracefully handle
>   receiving zero or more values. Without completely overhauling the
>   language’s execution model and turning it into Icon (which I find
>   strangely appealing, but probably not practical…), there aren’t too
>   many places that fit that constraint. Basically collection literals
>   and maybe positional argument lists. (I wrote [a proposal for the
>   latter](https://github.com/munificent/ui-as-code/blob/master/in-progress/parameter-freedom.md), but it’s quite complex so we aren’t doing it, at least not
>   right now.)

That proposal doesn't quite cover what you want, which is to spread a `Map` into optional named arguments, however.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that there is no way to *type check* the parameters this way. Even if the map had type `Map<Symbol, int>` and all the named parameters had type `int`, we still couldn't check whether the symbols in the map would correspond to method arguments. In practice, it would just be a run-time error waiting to happen. 
If we had constructor tear-offs (we should), then you could potentially do `Function.apply(Text, [text], textOptions)`. Sadly, you can't tear off constructors yet, so you'd have to make a function forwarding all the parameters.

Comment: Is this answer still up to date in 2022?

Comment: @cbr Nothing has changed for the spread operator; spreading an iterable as function arguments would still lose type information.   Constructor tear-offs do exist now, so the `Function.apply` example that lrn mentioned would work, however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the spread operator can be used with something else than `List` and arrays `[1, 2, 3]`.
Maybe you could first convert your Map to a List and then use the spread operator.