# How to pass the named paramaters in Dart to another Class instructor?

Tags: dart

For example I have A User class

```
class User {
 String name;
 String address;
 String weaponId;
 String weaponMerchant;
 Date weaponExpiration;

 Weapon weapon;

 User({this.name, this.address, this.weaponId, this.weaponMerchant, this.weaponExpiration}) {
  weapon = new Weapon(weaponId: weaponId, weaponMerchant: weaponMerchant, weaponExpiration: weaponExpiration);
 }
}

class Weapon {
 String id;
 
 Weapon({this.id, this.weaponId, this.weaponMerchant, this.weaponExpiration});
}
```

Are there any ways in dart where I can use spread operator or anything so that I don't need to pass these properties this one by one?

```
weapon = new Weapon(weaponId: weaponId, weaponMerchant: weaponMerchant, weaponExpiration: weaponExpiration);
```

Comment: spread operators are meant to be used with collections, you have to create the missing fields on the Weapon class. Using this. keyword in the constructor is already syntactic sugar for assigning a constructor argument to an instance variable.

Comment: See [Why I cant use spread operator in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277415/why-i-cant-use-spread-operator-in-this-case) for why you can't use the spread operator.

Comment: You compose User with Weapon
`User(Weapon weapon, name , address)`.

You can access `user.weapon.id`, why you need User object properties of Weapon? If they same - you will need twicely init them - for what reason? If they not same - if it's secondary weapon compose both User(Weapon weaponPrimary, Weapon weaponSecondary)?