# How to forward function arguments in Dart

Tags: function, dart, syntax

Is it possible to create function `g()` in Dart that accepts the same arguments as `f()` and then calls `f()` forwarding the received arguments?

```
int g(?...?) {
    f(?...?)
}
```

The tricky bit: if the interface of `f()` is updated, no changes to `g()` should be needed.

In JavaScript this can be achieved with the spread syntax, for example:

```
function f(a, b) {
    console.log("%d + %d = %d", a, b, a + b);
}

function g(...args) {
    f(...args);
}

g(1, 2);
```

Is it possible to create similar code in Dart despite strong typing? Function `f()` is known at the time `g()` is compiled.

Comment: Not possible since Dart does not support functions with variable number of arguments. The best alternative is to take a List as argument.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279163/