# Flutter/Dart Set Hour and Minutes in Current Date

Tags: flutter, dart

When i work with DateTime i receive the following params.

> I/flutter (25000): startTime: 13:46
>
> I/flutter (25000): endTime: 13:49

I manage to parse the date with this.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new DateFormat.Hm();
staticStartDate = dateFormat.parse(widget.startTime);
```

however the result date ends up like this:

> I/flutter (25000): 1970-01-01 13:46:00.000

when the result should be.

> I/flutter (25000): 2020-09-26 13:46:00.000

Anyone knows how to parse the time but with the current date?

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This question seems to be about constructing a `DateTime` object without needing to specify the date, whereas the supposed duplicate is about *formatting* a `DateTime`.  While I do think this question is a duplicate, I don't think that the linked question is the most appropriate one.

Comment: For example, I think https://stackoverflow.com/q/63770437/ is a closer match.