# Dart: Generate list of oauth2.Credentials from JSON without encoding items back to JSON for constructor

Tags: json, dart

While implementing a simple credential store based on JSON files I ran into a problem where I need to do a seemingly unnecessary roundtrip back to JSON for Dart's `oauth2.Credentials.fromJson()` constructor to work.

*Background: I am following the [oauth2 package's Authorization Code Grant example](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2#authorization-code-grant) but with the difference that instead of a single `Credentials` object, I want to save a list of `Credentials`.*

Here is a stripped-down version of my credential store:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:oauth2/oauth2.dart';

class CredentialStore {
  List<Credentials> get credentials {
    // credentials.json would contain a JSON array of objects created with oauth2.Credentials.toJson()
    final file = File('credentials.json');
    final jsonString = file.readAsStringSync();
    final List cred = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return List<Credentials>.from(cred.map((e) => Credentials.fromJson(e)));
  }
}
```

The last line is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter) and is accepted by the compiler but fails like this on runtime:

```
Unhandled exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

The code, however, runs successfully, if I take a round-trip back to JSON when mapping, like so:

```dart
return List<Credentials>.from(cred.map((e) => Credentials.fromJson(jsonEncode(e))));
```

This seems unnecessary and looks bad to me. Is this essentially a problem with the `Credentials.fromJson()` implementation in that it cannot accept maps already parsed from JSON or is it possible to rewrite my `get credentials` implementation in a way that avoids encoding back to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Credentials` class exposes the [Credentials()](https://pub.dev/documentation/oauth2/latest/oauth2/Credentials/Credentials.html) constructor, which is what `fromJson` also uses.

If you take a look at the implementation of the [`fromJson` factory](https://github.com/dart-lang/oauth2/blob/199ebf15cbd5b07958438184f32e41c4447a57bf/lib/src/credentials.dart#L130-L178), it does some basic validation on the JSON object (i.e. checks that it's valid JSON and the required fields are present) and passes the parsed data to `Credentials()`.

Since your data comes from `Credentials.toJson()` that you control yourself, it's probably safe to forgo the validation and use the constructor directly:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:oauth2/oauth2.dart';

class CredentialStore {
  List<Credentials> get credentials {
    final file = File('credentials.json');
    final jsonString = file.readAsStringSync();
    final List cred = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    
    return List<Credentials>.from(cred.map((parsed) {
      var tokenEndpoint = Uri.parse(parsed['tokenEndpoint']);
      var expiration = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(parsed['expiration']);
      return Credentials(
        parsed['accessToken'],
        refreshToken: parsed['refreshToken'],
        idToken: parsed['idToken'],
        tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint,
        scopes: (parsed['scopes'] as List).map((scope) => scope as String),
        expiration: expiration
      );
    }));
  }
}
```

Regarding your compiler error: in the answer you've linked, the `fromJson` method there operates on the result of a JSON decoded `Map`, whereas the `Credentials.fromJson()` factory operates on a String and as such does not expect the value passed to it to be already decoded.

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer! One more question: I was trying to use the constructor with the spread operator (`...`). Am I correct that it cannot be used in constructor calls or would it be possible to do something like `Credentials(parsed['accessToken'], ...rest)` to avoid writing out all of the field names? I suppose that would require some kind of casting for the types to work if at all possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Dart to know. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279163/996081) from 2019 says no, but that may have changed during the past 3 years.